# Count the number of the time records appears in 48 hrs- SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How do we select the count of the record that appears more than once in 48hrs?

for eg

```
ID DATE 
1  9/24/2018
1  9/23/2018
1  9/20/2018
2  9/20/2018
```

ID 1 APPEARED MORE THAN ONCE IN 48 HOURS

please let me know how to write a sql query to do this

Comment: T-SQL is generally from SQL Server, PL/SQL is generally from Oracle.  The syntax and available functionality is different in both.  When RDBMS are you actually using?

Comment: im using oracle

Comment: Your data doesnt show time. So you mean 2 days not 48 hours.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Umm, isn't that like saying You mean "2" not "20 tenths"?  *(What's the difference between 2 days and 48 hours?)*

Comment: @MatBailie I ask clarification because if there is a time on the data the calculation is different.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I can see your point, however I would contend that stating `48 hours` is the less ambiguous option.  Some might say that `2018-01-03 08:00` is within "2 days" from `2018-01-01 20:00`, others might say it's in the third calendar day and so doesn't count.  Saying "48 hours", however, makes that discrepancy go away.

Comment: Hello.. there is no time on the date yes 48 hours or 2 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways, but I'd start with using `LAG()` and a date comparison.  Assuming your DATE column is a date data-type?

```
WITH
  entity_summary AS
(
  SELECT
    ID,
    CASE
      WHEN LAG("DATE") OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY "DATE") >= "DATE" - INTERVAL '2' DAY
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END
      AS occurence_within_2_day
  FROM
    Table1
)
SELECT
  ID,
  SUM(occurence_within_2_day)
FROM
  entity_summary
GROUP BY
  ID
HAVING
  SUM(occurence_within_2_day) >= 1
```

Comment: Hi there. I try creating a fiddle and say cant put the lag function there. Can you take a look? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c2be3/2. Maybe have to do a subquery instead?

Comment: Hi .. when i run this query in toad I am getting an error window functions are not allowed in group by

Comment: Try this...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c2be3/28  *(I hate Oracle, sorry)*

Comment: WITH
  entity_summary AS
(
  SELECT
    pat_id,
    SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN LAG(event_dt_tm) OVER (PARTITION BY pat_id ORDER BY event_dt_tm) >= event_dt_tm - INTERVAL 2 DAY
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END
    )
      AS count_of_occurence_within_2_day
  FROM
    event
  GROUP BY
    pat_id
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  entity_summary
WHERE
  count_of_occurence_within_2_day >= 1

Comment: the fiddle is empty

Comment: it is empty again

Comment: It's intermittent.  SQL Fiddle is having problems.  Both links work.  Eventually.  Just keep trying them.

Comment: WITH
  entity_summary AS
(
  SELECT
    pat_id,
    CASE
      WHEN LAG(event_dt_tm) OVER (PARTITION BY pat_id ORDER BY event_dt_tm) >= event_dt_tm - INTERVAL '2' DAY
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END
      AS occurence_within_2_day
  FROM
    event
)
SELECT
  pat_id,
  SUM(occurence_within_2_day)
FROM
  entity_summary
GROUP BY
  pat_id
HAVING
  SUM(occurence_within_2_day) >= 1;